# Find all form elements and exclude empty fields and select elements with value -1

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to find all form elements and exclude empty fields and select element with value -1

I have tried this

```
$('form#myForm').find(":input[value!=''][value!='-1']");
```

This apply to all the elements but I need to apply `value!=-1` condition only to the select elements

Comment: do you mean dropdown when saying select elements??

Comment: @MilindAnantwar yes, I mean dropdown

Comment: added updated answer below....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use 'tag#id' nor '#id otherSelector' selectors see http://lab.abhinayrathore.com/jquery-standards/#Selectors

```
var $notEmptyInputs = $('#myForm').find(':input').filter(function(){
    var include = true;
    if (this.tagName == 'SELECT') {
        include = this.value !== '-1';
    } else {
        include = !!this.value;
    }
    return include;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use:

```
$("form#myForm select").filter(function(){
    return $(this).val() != -1;
}).add("form#myForm :input[value!='']:not(select)");
```

Answer (score 0):

isn't this:

```
$('form#myForm').find(":input[value='-1']");
```

This would let you filter only those elements which have a value of `-1` only.

Answer (score 0):

if the value is hard-coded, you can use:

```
$('form#myForm :input[value="-1"]');
```

else:

```
$('form#myForm :input').filter(function(){return this.value=='-1'})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over all inputs and do whatever you want

```
$('form#myForm :input[value!=""]').each(function() {
  var itemValue = this.val();
  if(itemValue != "-1" || itemValue == "Y")
    alert("Item value is " + itemValue);
});
```